# Node JS Memory Leak Scheduled/Cron Jobs

Tags: node.js, express, memory, cron

I have a GET route within my app which simply initiates a load of scheduled tasks/cron jobs (using NPM modules such as [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron) and [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule))

I have recently implemented some logic to do some scraping of some player information from [steam profiles](https://steamcommunity.com/) inside [repeatedRequests](https://github.com/avi312singh/FTYD-Express-App/blob/aggregatedStats/routes/repeatedRequests.js#L115) (main logic of my API). I have deployed my app to AWS which has allowed me to set up some basic monitoring and metrics of memory and CPU usage.

Looking at the MemoryUtilization chart [image: chart]

We can see that every 6 hours there is a constant incline in the memory usage of the app, which would point to the cron job I have recently introduced, am I not executing the cron job correctly? Could I handle promises better?

Is there also anything else inside repeatedRequests or other routes that I should or could be handling better which could be leading to memory leaks?

The larger requests made to the API start to slow down after about a day or a day and a half of the app starting from fresh, as you can see the memory usage has already increased 3 times since it started yesterday from 4% to 12% :O So I have to give it a manual reboot every week or it has crashed many times before too...

Thanks guys

[image: App has crashed before]

Comment: Why do you set up the cron jobs inside an HTTP route? Doesn't this mean that every time somebody does a GET request to "/", a new cron job will be created? Also, please check Steam terms and conditions - what you are doing might be against the TOS.

Comment: This particular route (repeatedRequests GET - where all the cron jobs exist) can only be hit once before the app is started again... I did check their API t and cs and found nothing against web scraping but also found they mentioned: You are limited to one hundred thousand (100,000) calls to the Steam Web API per day. Valve may approve higher daily call limits if you adhere to these API Terms of Use. So I am well within that limit

Comment: Honestly, nothing obvious pops up when looking at the code. Try running it locally and using heap dumps with Chrome's memory inspector to locate the issue.

Comment: @RobertKawecki Thanks for having a look... I have tried that but can't seem to find anything .. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake, the cron job was set to start a new job every minute from every 6th, creating an infinite amount of new jobs that were stacking on each other

Since then the syntax has been changed to every 6th hour from

`* */6 * * *` to `0 */6 * * *` and the memory usage is now sitting at a constant 7%, happy days!

[image: New memory usage]

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue in node-cron ([#358](https://github.com/node-cron/node-cron/issues/358)) where there is excessive memory use due to [a bug in NodeJS](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/31914).

Apparently the bug was fixed in Node v12.20.0, but I'm running v18.4.0 and still seeing the problem.

At the time of writing (Sep 2022) there is a PR that seems to work around the problem ([#366](https://github.com/node-cron/node-cron/pull/366)), however it has yet to be merged.

Comment: nodejs v18.11.0 still ocurred. "croner" is alternative.

Comment: I also switched to the `croner` module instead as it seems `node-cron` is not interested in fixing the bug.  It was minimal work switching modules as the functions are very similar.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue but this because I added the timezone to options

```
cron.schedule('0 22 * * *', () => {
    console.log('Cron Job started');
    CronService.notifyTomorrowShifts();
  },{
      timezone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
   });
```

once I remove it its working just fine

I was in Node 18